# Can we find which search terms came from which browser in google analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

In google analytics we can see the site search terms in the behavior section. Is there a way I can see which browser was used for these search terms. Forexample I want to see how many times iphone 7 was searched from mobile chrome browsers ?

or

which search pages came from mobile browsers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser or mobile device as a **secondary dimension**. If you want to combine different dimensions with logical operators (like AND, OR) you can use **custom segments**.